# add swipe tab to fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, swipe

Hi everybody,this is my app

[image]
[image]

I wanna add 2 swipe tab Accounts Activity and Chart to a fragment_accounts.xml layout.
I have navigation drawer menu too.

this is fragment_accounts.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

and this is AccountsFragment.java:
I get this error

> Error:(44, 33) error: incompatible types: android.app.ActionBar cannot
>   be converted to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.R;
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;


public class AccountsFragment extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Accounts Acctivity", "Chart Activity"};

    public AccountsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_accounts, container, false);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

and this is TabsPagerAdapter: I get this error:

> Error:(25, 24) error: incompatible types: AccountsActivityFragment
>   cannot be converted to Fragment

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.AccountsActivityFragment;
import com.rastari.salar.mymetarialbank.activity.ChartActivity;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                return new AccountsActivityFragment();

            case 1:
                return new ChartActivity();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 2;
    }
}
```

I searched whole the internet to find how to create an app with navigation drawer menu and swipe tabs tutorial, but i found nothing.

please help this is very important to me.
thank you.

Comment: try to use only common lib (android.v4) or v7

Answer (score 0):

For your actionBar
You should be calling `getSupportActionBar`() instead of `getActionBar()`

For your fragment, make sure they both extend the `android.support.v4.Fragment` and not the `android.app.Fragment`

Comment: I used android.support.v4.app.Fragment for all and getSupportActionBar()  doesn't work!!